Finding Missing Entries in a Map Based on Another Map
I'm trying to identify the entries missing from one map (toCheckForCommonStrings) compared to another map (commonString). Here's my attempt so far:
public void compareCommonStrings(Map<String, String> mapWithMissingCommonStrings) {
    int cntr = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : commonURIsCls.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey().replace("<","").replace(">","").trim();
        String value = entry.getValue().replace("<","").replace(">","").trim();

        if ((!commonString.containsKey(key) && !commonString.containsValue(value))) {
            labeled_class_mappings.put(key, value); // a protected field
            cntr++;
        }
    }
}

However, some strings seem to be missing, and I'm unsure why. Both commonString and mapWithMissingCommonStrings are maps of type Map<String, String>. The code should find out entries from commonString are not present in mapWithMissingCommonStrings. However I don't understand why is this happening... Could someone please help me identify what might be causing the missing strings?
Thank you in advance

if ((!commonString.containsKey(key) && !commonString.containsValue(value))) { You're aware that that is not looking for one entry aren't you? What would be is if (value != null && !value.equals(commonString.get(key))

@g00se
Thank you for you help. I didn't know that... However is this solution you provided the fastest though?

Well I'm not saying it is a solution yet ;) Did you try it? I was just making a general point, as, for one thing, I'm not quite sure what's going on with your code

@g00se
I already tried it and it is what I wanted :). Yet, I was wondering what would be the fastest, maybe using stream() function?

I don't think any difference such as you mention would be significant. If those angle brackets are the first and last char then you might do key = key.replaceAll("^<|>$", "");
